# Strange MariaDB Issue LEFT JOIN SUM with multi GROUP BY Column

Tags: group-by, mariadb

I Have strange issue on maria db in this query:

```
SELECT
tr_sales_delivery_detail.sales_order_id,
tr_sales_delivery_detail.row_id,
tr_sales_delivery_detail.qty_delivery,
so.qty AS so_qty
FROM tr_sales_delivery_detail
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tr_sales_order_detail.item_id, 
             tr_sales_order_detail.row_id,  
             tr_sales_order_detail.sales_order_id,
             SUM(tr_sales_order_detail.qty) AS qty FROM tr_sales_order_detail
    GROUP BY tr_sales_order_detail.item_id, tr_sales_order_detail.row_id, tr_sales_order_detail.sales_order_id
) so
ON so.item_id = tr_sales_delivery_detail.item_id
AND so.row_id = tr_sales_delivery_detail.row_id
AND so.sales_order_id = tr_sales_delivery_detail.sales_order_id
WHERE tr_sales_delivery_detail.sales_delivery_id = '10923';
```

return :

| sales_order_id | row_id | Qty Delivery | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11062 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 11062 | 11 | 1 | null |

, but when I concat the group by it return the correct value

```
SELECT 
tr_sales_delivery_detail.sales_order_id,
tr_sales_delivery_detail.row_id,
tr_sales_delivery_detail.qty_delivery ,
so.qty AS so_qty
FROM tr_sales_delivery_detail
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tr_sales_order_detail.item_id, 
             tr_sales_order_detail.row_id,  
             tr_sales_order_detail.sales_order_id,
             SUM(tr_sales_order_detail.qty) AS qty FROM tr_sales_order_detail
    GROUP BY concat(tr_sales_order_detail.item_id, tr_sales_order_detail.row_id, tr_sales_order_detail.sales_order_id)
) so
ON so.item_id = tr_sales_delivery_detail.item_id
AND so.row_id = tr_sales_delivery_detail.row_id
AND so.sales_order_id = tr_sales_delivery_detail.sales_order_id
WHERE tr_sales_delivery_detail.sales_delivery_id = '10923';
```

return

| sales_order_id | row_id | Qty Delivery | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11062 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 11062 | 11 | 1 | 1 |

Can someone explain what happen with first query? does it mariadb bug?

---

after some research, I found it related with column index key
column item_id, row_id, and sales_order_id have index key.
when I remove index key for column sales_order_id, it return normal.

data type for each column (item_id, row_id, sales_order_id) is :
bigint(20)

Can someone explain does my index is wrong or it related to bug ?

It is return null only if the next row has same sales_order_id value.

### I want to remove concat usage in group by, because its affect the performance

I Think its related to this bug https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26337

Comment: Both queries look identical to me, and both look valid.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: The difference is concat at group by statement